# Only run an executable File once in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, exe

I created a program in C++ and created its executable File. My program reads from a huge chunk of files, and then I only need to perform computations on it. So in short I only want to run my executable file once and then just need to pass command line arguments to get the result.

```
const execFile = require('child_process').execFile;
const child = execFile('./a.out',[InArr], (error, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (error) {
    throw error;
  }
  console.log(stdout);
});
```

But the problem with the above line is, it will execute my code every single time, therefore I need to do all the extra work(reading files), again.
Is there some other way to do it more efficiently?

Comment: I am sorry, but your question is completely unclear. Also is this javascript? Why did you tag c++? the fact that `a.out` was coded with such language appears to be completely irrelevant

Comment: Are you reading the files in C++, and is it only able to perform one “computation” at a time? You should probably show that program in addition/instead.